# CSS scale transform affecting position calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that I show and position over another element. When I apply a CSS transform to the entire body, the position isn't calculated correctly anymore. Here's the javascript:

```
function Start() {

  $('#ScaleBodyBtn').click(function() {

    $('body').css({
      'transform': 'scale(1.5)',
      'transform-origin': 'top left'
    });
  });

  $('#ShowOverlayBtn').click(function() {

    var ThePosition = $('#ShowOverlayBtn').offset();

    $('#Overlay').css({
      'top': ThePosition.top,
      'left': ThePosition.left
    }).show();

  });
}

$(Start);
```

Here's the HTML/CSS

```
<input id="ScaleBodyBtn" type="button" value="scale body" />
<input id="ShowOverlayBtn" type="button" value="show overlay" />
<div id="Overlay"></div>

#ShowOverlayBtn,
#ScaleBodyBtn {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: 50px 30px;
}

#Overlay {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

And here's [the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45bv6fd0/) that replicates the problem. You click Show Overlay and it appears right over the button. Refresh and press Scale Body first and this time when you click on the Show Overlay button the red div is not in the correct place.

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Hi, this is an old post hehe, but I am facing a similar issue with some elements positioning themselves away from where they should when scale is applied. Did you figure out a solution? It would be helpful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your position is calculated ok.

But your overlay is inside the body, and so it is also affected by the transform that you set in it.

Set it on another, untransformed div, and you are ok.

```js
function Start() {

  $('#ScaleBodyBtn').click(function() {

    $('#body').css({
      'transform': 'scale(1.5)',
      'transform-origin': 'top left'
    });
  });

  $('#ShowOverlayBtn').click(function() {

    var ThePosition = $('#ShowOverlayBtn').offset();

    $('#Overlay').css({
      'top': ThePosition.top,
      'left': ThePosition.left
    }).show();

  });
}

$(Start);
```

```css
#ShowOverlayBtn,
#ScaleBodyBtn {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: 50px 30px;
}

#Overlay {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#body2 {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
<input id="ScaleBodyBtn" type="button" value="scale body" />
<input id="ShowOverlayBtn" type="button" value="show overlay" />
</div>
<div id="body2">
<div id="Overlay"></div>
</div>
```